# RequireJS optimizer and TFS Build

Tags: build, tfs, requirejs

I'm looking at using RequireJS to organise my JavaScript files in an ASP.NET MVC project. I'd want to call the RequireJS optimizer r.js as part of a TFS Build to combine+minify my JavaScript and CSS files.

I'm wondering whether this makes sense and how to implement this in a build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Node will install without problem (consider taking the agents with it).  From there, use the InvokeProcess activity to run `node <path>/<to>/r.js -o build.app.js`.

I would include r.js in the project source rather than put it on the build servers.  That'll make it easier to practice the build locally.  You'll want to use the ConvertWorkspaceItem activity to get the path to build.app.js.

The other thing you'll want to consider is removing those resources that have been concatenated and uglified.  Not essential, but I prefer doing this by copying the modules I expect from the build.app.js to my final deployable package directory.